# iOS register push notification issue

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

In my past experience, if we have to use push notification, we need to register the user notification settings in AppDelegate, and put the register code in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions; the warning message will appear when the user launches this app for the first time.

Due to my company's plan, we don't want to show this warning message at the first time app launched, but shows when the user enters the specific page.

I tired and it worked to get the device token in AppDelegate, application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken.

But I'm afraid that if we don't follow the spec Apple gave us, something strange will happened. Did you guys had similar experience with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, for appstore approval it is not a requirement to ask notification permission at the first launch. For example, some apps show some sort of wizard to set things up and they only ask permission when you click a button to enable push notifications.

This page might be usefull, though for this particular question you'll need the appstore approval guidelines, which I think we may not link to due to the developer agreement.

https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/features/notifications/

Comment: Thanks! I tried to find App Store approval guidelines, and there is no requirement to ask the permission at the first launch. I will update the result as our company submit the app.

Comment: It seems it's okey to ask notification permission at the other screen. My company's app just passed Apple's review.